# Regex to match words and phrases

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex to match exact words and phrases even if they intersects

For example I have this line

"The black horse is known for its black colour ... etc"

and I have input list of words to match and replace : "black" , "yellow", "black horse"... etc

The regex should match 
"black" in "black colour"
 and "black horse" in "The black horse"
but not "black" in "black horse"

How can I stop "black" to be matched in "black horse"?

I am using java code

```
String regex="\\b" + word + "\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(article);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `negative lookahead`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bblack (?!horse\\b)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

This will match `black`  that is not followed by `horse`.

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bV0jE5)

Comment: This is the way to do it, basically means "match "black" if not followed directly by "horse""

Comment: What are other cases? I didn't see them in question.

Comment: It's not only this case I have unlimited general cases where wordx is followed by wordy or wordz and I have to match wordx , wordx wordy, wordx wordz

Comment: @Sara: You can use similar approach i.e. this regex `"\\bblack (?!(horse|wordx|wordy|wordz)\\b)"`

Comment: always exceptional approach!! +1 :)

Comment: I don't know wordx|wordy|wordz. I have a list of words to match for example: black, black horse, yellow, black animal, animal...

Comment: @Sara : i mean no offense to you, but you sound confused, if you *don't know wordx|wordy|wordz* and have list of words, may be you can pass it to the `regex` for matching through some loop or filter....makes sense??

Comment: I am not confused. How can you loop a list of unknown input and not knowing how to process it? I gave an example in the previous comment. There are many possibilities I have to prevent ("black", "animal" not matching in "black animal" is one case)

Comment: @Sara: Main issue is that your question is not matching the problem you are stating in your comments. If you have a different problem then first edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: You edited question is still unclear on what you want. These question attract far many answers otherwise. If you can provide a sample input and your expected output that will also help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this expression `(?!black horse)black`